# How to get integer / float number from a string representation ( array of bytes ) delivered to python using zmq / zeromq?

Tags: python, c++, pyzmq

I'm using a C++ server and a few Python clients with `zmq` ( ZeroMQ ) lib. I would like to send a **`float`** and an **`integer`** to the clients.

I have read through the manual for `zmq`, but I have a problem sending anything else than a **`char array`** from the C++ code, which can not be interpreted by the `python` client as `integer` or `float`.

My C++ code looks like this:

```
//  Socket to talk to clients
void *context = zmq_ctx_new();
void *responder = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_REP);
int rc = zmq_bind(responder, "tcp://*:5555");
int msg_cnt = 0;

while (1) {     
    char data[] = "M3:155";
    sendCommand(responder, data);
}

static void sendCommand(void* r, char* cmd) {

    static int n;
    char buffer[10];
    zmq_recv(r, buffer, 10, 0);

    zmq_send(r, cmd, sizeof(cmd), 0);
    std::cout << std::to_string(n++) << ". command sent." << std::endl;

    Sleep(1);
}
```

And the python client is something like this:

```
context = zmq.Context()

#  Socket to talk to server
print("Connecting to hello world server")
socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
socket.connect("tcp://localhost:5555")

#print("Sending request %s ")
socket.send(b"I am here.")

#  Get the reply.
message = socket.recv()
#message = b"M5:-"
print("Received reply [%s]" % (message))

match = re.match(b'.*(M\d+):(\d+)', message)

print ("Command is: ", match.group())
print ("Motor: ", match.group(1))
print ("Target Angle: ", match.group(2))
```

**Output for python:**

Received reply `[b'M3:155\x00\xcc']`
Command is: `b'M3:155'`
Motor: `b'M3'`
Target Angle: `b'155'`

How can I parse the `b'155'` as an `int` or `float`?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erm...

```
3>> float(b'155')
155.0
```

Comment: I have forgot to mention that I am a Python lame, using it for about 4 hours. :) Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: @ToMmY_hun: Then I would recommend taking the time to go through [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), seeing as how you already have some skill in at least one other programming language.

Comment: Yeah I will do that, but now I have to finish a project until Friday. Thank you for your help!